# How to stop amp from intercepting a style?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, amp-html

I am trying to implement amp on my site. But When I use amp, it is changing some of the designs. Then I added !important to the css styles. It worked but broke my amp validity. So, How can I keep my styles as well as keep it amp valid.

This is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html amp>

<style>
<script async custom-element="amp-autocomplete" src="../../../cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-autocomplete-0.1.js"></script>
</style>

<body>
<amp-autocomplete filter="substring" min-characters="0" style="padding: 0; color: black; display: inherit;" class="display_fix">
<body>
```

it doesn't displays the element as display:inherit;
It works when I use display:inherit !important;
But it makes the page amp invalid.

You can check the site live from here: https://mydoginsurance.com.au/pet-insurance/cover-type/index-no-important.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of AMP validity is to prevent people from overriding styles it deems as required. You would need to write the code in a different way in order to achieve a similar effect, if you want to maintain AMP validity. The URL you listed in 404ing, I would however be happy to suggest alternatives if you relist the content

source: work at Google on AMP